# Django 1.3 - RequestContext not rendering to template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to simply render {{ request.user }} from my base template and for whatever reason it is not rendering anything. I have even tested trying to return {{ request }} to no avail.

I am currently using django-annoying to render to the template (render_to) and have tried to switch back to using django.templates.RequestContext and that hasn't worked either.

I have a feeling it has something to do with caching, but I have edited my template to show test - {{ request }} and "test - " shows up just fine.

I have also tried to upgrade my django to 1.4 alpha to see if it resolves my issue.

**This does not send the request to the template**

```
@render_to('profile/index.html')
def home(request):
    return {}
```

**This works**

```
@render_to('profile/index.html')
def home(request):
    return {'request': request}
```

However, if I pass 'request': request into the template everything works.

Link to [settings.py](https://gist.github.com/1023758)

I can give any more information that is requested.

Comment: In Django 1.3, there's no need for Django-annoying and its `render_to` decorator any more - at long last, this is built in, with the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut.

Comment: Can't you just use `{{ user }}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the [`django.core.context_processors.request`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request) context processor.

Comment: Yup. JUST realized that looking at my past projects. *sigh*